# Cannot send messages to all clients

Tags: java, networking, client-server, chat

I want to send a message from the server to all the clients.

My approach is to make an ArrayList of all the clients that are currently connected the server.
If any client sends a message, I iterate through the ArrayList and send each of the clients the message.

The problem is that my clients are not receiving any message.

Here is my send method on server-side:

```
private void message() {
    while (true) {
        DataInputStream fromClient;
        try {
            fromClient = new DataInputStream(socketNew.getInputStream());
            message = fromClient.readUTF();
            for (Socket s:socs) {
                System.out.println(message);

                DataOutputStream toClient = newDataOutputStream( s.getOutputStream() );
                toClient.writeUTF(message);
            }
            message="";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

Here is my receive method on client side:

```
private void receive_data() {

    {
        DataInputStream fromServer;
        try {
            fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            message = fromServer.readUTF();
            console(message);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Any suggestions on where I might be doing it all wrong?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't mix `println()` and `readUTF().` The only thing that `readUTF()` will understand is data written by `writeUTF().`
- You need to use the same streams or readers/writers for the life of the socket.

Comment: Where am I mixing println() and readUTF?Are you referring to System.out.println(message)?

Answer (score -1):

You are writing to OutputStream but are not flushing them.

```
 for(Socket s:socs)
 {
      System.out.println(message);
      DataOutputStream toClient=newDataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
      toClient.writeUTF(message);
      toClient.flush();
 }
```

You must also make sure that server is recieving any message from socketNew socket. Because it may be blocked on waiting for input at line:

```
message=fromClient.readUTF();
```

By the way, creating new DataOutputStream for every message isn't good approach.

Comment: I flushed it but to no avail.Can you tell me some alternate approach to this?

Comment: Check out second half of my answer. Are you sure that you recieve message. Try replacing message=fromClient.readUTF(); with some sample message like message = "foo";

Comment: `DataOutputStreams` don't need flushing, unless there is a `BufferedOutputStream` underneath, which there isn't here.